# Get access to form element from another method of form's class in C#

Tags: c#, forms, listview

I'm using ListView item in my C# project, and I'd like to add some data to it. I've created a method in the form's class, but for some reason I can't access ListView from that method. I can only access it from some events of that form(i.e. button click). Here is the function I created

```
 public static void addToList(string complexity, string processors, string selectedProc)
    {
        string[] row = { DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff"), complexity, processors, selectedProc };
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
        //tasksList.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }
```

The commented line is the one which returns an error. This method is located in `public partial class Form1 : Form`

Full Form1 class code

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    processors system1;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void startButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        system1 = new processors(proc1Speed.Text, proc2Speed.Text, proc3Speed.Text, proc4Speed.Text, proc5Speed.Text, possibility.Text);

    }

    private void millisecond_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        system1.addTask();
    }

    public static void addToList(string complexity, string processors, string selectedProc)
    {
        string[] row = { DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss:ff"), complexity, processors, selectedProc };
        var listViewItem = new ListViewItem(row);
        //tasksList.Items.Add(listViewItem);
    }


}
```

Comment: can you show the code / class and definition of where `tasksList` is defined. what is it's scope.. is it `private, public, static` , etc...?

Comment: tasksList is a ViewList I've added on my form.

Comment: what's it's access level by default it's `private` also I think that showing all relevant code in regards to your issue will provide being useful..

Comment: I've added full Form1 class code to my question.

Comment: what is the code of the class that wants to call addToList ?

Comment: Is it ok if I post all 225 lines?

Comment: yep, there will be a scrollbar.

Comment: I've found a solution for my problem. I'll post it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the static keyword from the method. Why did you put it there in the first place ?
A static method cannot access instance variables of the objects created of the class the static method belongs to.

Comment: without seeing all of his code it's hard to determine why or why not the op has implemented a static variable.. other than that your other part of the statement is correct..

Comment: But then I won't be able to access it from another class of the project.

Comment: from the other class you have to do something like form.addToList, assuming that you did form = new Form(...). But that is already a different problem. Show more code please. How do you create your form1, what code is in the 'other' class.

Comment: You 100% for sure have to remove the static keyword. Then focus on the other problem which is how to call a method on the instance of form1 from a different class.

Comment: I've tried using `Form1 myForm = Form1.ActiveForm;`, but VS says that this is implicit conversion.

Answer (score 0):

So I've found a way out. As you can see there is `millisecond_Tick` method in my code. It calls method from another class `system1.addTask();` and that is the class from which I wanted to add data to my ListView. So I pass my applications form to that method with `system1.addTask(this);`. So that method looks like that `public void addTask(Form1 form)`. In method's body I can access all form elements using `form.elementname`. Thanks everyone for participating!

Comment: Please mark my answer as solution or at least upvote it.